# Why does mysqli_real_escape_string() require two params?

Tags: php, mysqli, php-5.3

Could someone explain this to me please.

Let's take a look at this script.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security

$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If the job of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is to escape characters in a string, why does it need the connection along with it, if it's already within the script above?
Not forgetting the fact that `mysqli_real_escape_string()` escapes characters from a variable of some kind value and not from database.

And if it was from a database, it would only make sense to even use it if the same exact data was to be re-insterted back into a database, would it not?

Comment: From the docs *"taking into account the current charset of the connection"*. Escaping is different, or can be, from character set to character set.

Comment: One reason is that it is more secure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does it need the connection along with it, if it's already within the script above?

The function doesn't know *which* connection you want, you need to pass it explicitly. Should you open more than one connection to several databases, you will have to pass one connection explicitly. Implicitly passing the last connection was a bad practice prevalent in ext/mysql, it's not sane for any typical software development.

Now, why does it need a connection at all? Because it needs to know the **connection encoding**. When issuing a query, you're sending a simple byte stream of data to the database. The database interprets this byte stream in the set connection encoding to turn it into characters it can read to understand what you want from it. The same character may be encoded entirely differently in different encodings. Therefore the escaping function needs to know what character encoding it needs to deal with to correctly escape characters. It is possible to exploit SQL injection vulnerabilities if this is not done properly.

Answer (score 4):

Because `mysqli_real_escape_string()` needs to be aware of the character encodings of the database you'll be putting data into.

It doesn't automatically assume a specific connection because if you're connected to multiple databases, you don't want it to guess which one you meant.